# multiple mail recipients with CakePHP using bcc (the right insert method)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i use the php framework cakePHP to create a web app. There,i want the user to insert in a field as many email addresses as he desires and by hitting the Send button,a message would be emailed to all of the emails.

To achieve that,i have to use bcc.

My problem is that i do not know how can i "read" from the user his email addresses in the right form so that i use them in bcc.

Till now,i have a variable $to = $this->request->data['Mail']['to']; ,where 'Mail' is my model name,and in case the user inserts just one email address,the recipient receives the mail correctly. But how can i enable it to receive multiple email addresses (maybe in an array??) so that i use the variable $to at this piece of code:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();

$Email->from($from)
    ->**bcc($to)**
    ->subject($subject)
    ->send($message);
```

and help is welcomed :)

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is the API ( http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeEmail.html#_addBcc ) and the code is open source. They all provide the information you are looking for.

If you open the class CakeEmail you will find ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L482 ):

```
public function addBcc()
```

which is different from bcc() since it can be used multiple times to add multiple bcc addresses.

Comment: i tried to use this function (here is my code also http://pastie.org/7819325) but this does not work either. It throws me an error :  Call to a member function addBcc() on a non-object :/

Comment: @koslibpro that's because you're trying to access `$this->Email` (which doesn't exist) in stead of the variable `$Email` (the variable you used for your instance of CakeEmail)